# Is it possible to configure MySQL to return TIMESTAMP value as a UNIXTIMESTAMP?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to configure MySQL to return TIMESTAMP value as a UNIXTIMESTAMP by default, rather than casting every column in the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a function to convert a date to a unix timestamp.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
        -> 1196440210
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');
        -> 1196440219
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in MySQL configuration.

You can do that on application level - e.g. in PHP, you can use the `mysqli_result::fetch_fields()` method to detect timestamp type and convert it, other connectors will have similar methods.

Or you can do it - as suggested - using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function on timestamp columns.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want a different view of the same data:

```
mysql> select * from t;
+------+---------------------+
| data | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
| foo  | 2013-03-19 16:54:45 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select data, unix_timestamp(ts) from t;
+------+--------------------+
| data | unix_timestamp(ts) |
+------+--------------------+
| foo  |         1363712085 |
+------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create view tv (data, time_t) as select data, unix_timestamp(ts) from t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tv;
+------+------------+
| data | time_t     |
+------+------------+
| foo  | 1363712085 |
+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```